# How can I both horizontally and vertically center two divs inside another div?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, alignment

What I am trying to do should look like this:

[image: horizontally/vertically aligned inner divs]

...but my `inner_top` div (with the *red* background) is *not* **horizontally-centered**, and ends up looking like this:

[image: all jacked up!]

The conflict appears to be using `display: inline-block'` on the `inner_top` div, which is what appears to make it **vertically-centered** though, except for a weird spacing between the two divs.

---

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            CSS sucks!!!
        </title>

        <style type = "text/css">

            #outer {
                width: 250px;
                height: 500px;
                border: 5px solid black;

                /* for vertically-centering inner divs: */
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
                    #inner_top {
                        width: 75px;
                        height: 175px;
                        background-color: red;

                        /* horizontally-centered: */
                        margin: 0 auto;

                        /* vertically-center both this and the bottom div:
                        (but now horizontal-alignment doesn't work on this div!) */
                        display: inline-block;

                    }
                    #inner_bottom {
                        width: 150px;
                        height: 150px;
                        background-color: blue;

                        /* horizontally-centered: */
                        margin: 0 auto;
                    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "outer">

            <div id = "inner_top">
            </div> <!-- end of inner top -->

            <div id = "inner_bottom">
            </div> <!-- end of inner_bottom -->
        </div> <!-- end of outer div -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I remove the `display:inline-block`, the example works fine for me...

Comment: +1 for above. http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/MhbmY/

Comment: Haha, amazing! I can't believe I didn't try that... duh, I feel like a dummy. @MrLister -- if you post this as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your code in a jsfiddle, and it works when when I remove the `display:inline-block` from the top div's style.
See http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5ZHdK/

```
/*display: inline-block;*/
```

Still not sure where your remark "vertically-center both this and the bottom div" comes from though; it sounds like you couldn't get it to work without the inline-block?

Comment: Thanks @MrLister. I was getting vertical and horizontal alignment confused after testing several different things, where `display: inline-block;` set on both inner divs would align them next to one another...

Answer (score 1):

just centre them using this simple chunk of css

```css
#inner_top {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#inner_bottom {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: `margin:0 auto` was already present in both the `inner_top` and `inerr_bottom` CSS, which is equivalent to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `margin:0 auto` for all child elements you are trying to center.

Children with `margin:0 auto` can not be block types.

http://jsfiddle.net/EDpgS/

Comment: `margin:0 auto` was present in both child elements, but as you are saying `display: inline-block;` is the problem.

Comment: Margins don't work on inline elements at all.  Inline elements are centered via `text-align: center`.